# how to get account Name in contact query

Tags: soql, account

I am fetching account name in this query.

```
public class contactcon{
    List<contact> con = [Select id,name,accountName from contact];
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use dot(.) between account.name

```
List con = [Select id,name,account.Name from contact]
```